# Parsing Twitter JSON object in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to download tweets from twitter.

I have used python and Tweepy for this. Though I am new to both Python and Twitter API.

My Python script is as follow:
    #!usr/bin/python

```
#import modules
import sys
import tweepy
import json

#global variables
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
token_key = ''
token_secret = ''

#Main function
def main():
    print sys.argv[0],'starts'
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(token_key, token_secret)
    print 'Connected to Twitter'
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    if not api.test():
        print 'Twitter API test failed'

    print 'Experiment with cursor'
    print 'Get search method returns json objects'

   json_search = api.search(q="football")
   #json.loads(json_search())
   print  json_search


#Standard boilerplate to call main function if this file runs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting result as follows:

```
[<tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a0934c>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a0986c>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a096ec>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0xb76d8ccc>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a09ccc>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a0974c>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a0940c>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x99fdfcc>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x99fdfec>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a08cec>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a08f4c>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a08eec>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a08a4c>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a08c0c>, <tweepy.models.SearchResult object at 0x9a08dcc>]
```

Now I am confused how to extract tweets from this information?
I tried to use json.loads method on this data. But it gives me error as JSON expects string or buffer. 
Example code would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take my code for tweepy:

```
def twitterfeed():
   auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
   auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
   api = tweepy.API(auth)
   statuses = tweepy.Cursor(api.home_timeline).items(20)
   data = [s.text.encode('utf8') for s in statuses]
   print data
```

Answer (score 8):

Tweepy gives you richer objects; it parsed the JSON for you.

The `SearchResult` objects have the same attributes as the JSON structures that Twitter sent; just look up the [Tweet documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets) to see what is available:

```
for result in api.search(q="football"):
    print result.text
```

Demo:

```
>>> import tweepy
>>> tweepy.__version__
'3.3.0'
>>> consumer_key = '<consumer_key>'
>>> consumer_secret = '<consumer_secret>'
>>> access_token = '<access_token>'
>>> access_token_secret = '<access_token_secret>'
>>> auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
>>> auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
>>> api = tweepy.API(auth)
>>> for result in api.search(q="football"):
...     print result.text
... 
Great moments from the Women's FA Cup http://t.co/Y4C0LFJed9
RT @freebets: 6 YEARS AGO TODAY: 

Football lost one of its great managers. 

RIP Sir Bobby Robson. http://t.co/NCo90ZIUPY
RT @Oddschanger: COMPETITION CLOSES TODAY!

Win a Premier League or Football League shirt of YOUR choice! 

RETWEET &amp; FOLLOW to enter. http…
Berita Transfer: Transfer rumours and paper review – Friday, July 31 http://t.co/qRrDIEP2zh [TS] #nobar #gosip
@ajperry18 im sorry I don't know this football shit
@risu_football おれモロ誕生日で北辰なんすよ笑
NFF Unveils Oliseh As Super Eagles Coach - SUNDAY Oliseh has been unveiled by the Nigeria Football... http://t.co/IOYajD9bi2 #Sports
RT @BilelGhazi: RT @lequipe : Gourcuff, au tour de Guingamp http://t.co/Dkio8v9LZq
@EDS_Amy HP SAUCE ?
RT @fsntweet: マンＣの塩対応に怒りの炎！ベトナム人ファン、チケットを燃やして猛抗議 - http://t.co/yg5iuABy3K 

なめるなよ、プレミアリーグ！マンチェスターＣのプレシーズンツアーの行き先でベトナム人男性が、衝撃的な行
RT @peterMwendo: Le football cest un sport collectif ou on doit se faire des passe http://t.co/61hy138yo8
RT @TSBible: 6 years ago today, football lost a true gentleman. Rest in Peace Sir Bobby Robson. http://t.co/6eHTI6UxaC
6 years ago today the greatest football manger of all time passed away SIR Bobby Robson a true Ipswich and footballing legend
The Guardian: PSG close to sealing £40m deal for Manchester United’s Ángel Di María. http://t.co/gAQEucRLZa
Sir Bobby Robson, the #football #legend passed away 6 years ago. 

#Barcelona #newcastle #Porto http://t.co/4UXpnvrHhS
```

Comment: nope this causes an error in latest tweepy AttributeError: 'SearchResults' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @loretoparisi: read my answer *carefully*. The `SearchResult` object is a *list* of statuses. Each status has a `.text` attribute, the list itself does not.

Comment: @loretoparisi: this is why I *iterate* over the results. The `for result in api.search(..)` loop is important here; each `result` object is a status. The `api.search()` result object is a `SearchResult` object and does not directly support access to status attributes.

Comment: @martijin-pieters yes I replied below with my solution for that.

Comment: @loretoparisi: that doesn't explain anything about why you felt my answer was wrong.

Comment: @loretoparisi: the default is to use a `ModelParser`; you are now producing *dictionaries*, not model instances, so you do not get a `text` attribute, you get a `'text'` dictionary key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **JSON parser** to achieve this, here is my code on App Engine that handles a **JSONP** response ready to be used in with a JQuery client:

```
import webapp2
import tweepy
import json
from tweepy.parsers import JSONParser

class APISearchHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxx'
        CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxx'
        ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = 'xxxx'
        ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxx'

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
        api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=JSONParser())

        # Query String Parameters
        qs = self.request.get('q')
        max_id = self.request.get('max_id')

        # JSONP Callback
        callback = self.request.get('callback')

        max_tweets = 100
        search_results = api.search(q=qs, count=max_tweets, max_id=max_id)
        json_str = json.dumps( search_results )

        if callback:
            response = "%s(%s)" % (callback, json_str)
        else:
            response = json_str

        self.response.write( response )
```

So the key point is

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=JSONParser())
```

Comment: Why use the JSONParser *at all*? Why does this solve the OP question? All you are doing is alter what is returned; now you get the raw JSON responses instead of rich Python objects.

Comment: I don't know if it solves the question, but looking at the question "Now I am confused how to extract tweets from this information? I tried to use json.loads method on this data. But it gives me error as JSON expects string or buffer. Example code would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance." I think so btw it's my opinion.

Comment: I'm asking because you downvoted my answer on the basis of an error my code doesn't actually produce. Your solution doesn't produce JSON data *either*, it produces Python datastructures (lists, dictionaries, strings, floats, booleans and `None`), decoded from the JSON payload from Twitter. I'm puzzled as to why you are using a non-default parser here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using global variables, I would reorganize the code in a python `class`:

```
import tweepy

class TweetPrinter():
    """
        Simple class to print tweets
    """
    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, 
                 access_token_secret):
        self.consumer_key = consumer_key
        self.consumer_secret = consumer_secret
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.access_token_secret = access_token_secret
        self.auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(self.consumer_key, 
                                        self.consumer_secret)
        self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    def tweet_print(self):
        api = tweepy.API(self.auth)
        football_tweets = api.search(q="football")
        for tweet in football_tweets:
            print(tweet.text)


def main():
    tweet_printer = TweetPrinter(my_consumer_key, my_consumer_secret, 
                              my_access_token, my_access_token_secret)

    tweet_printer.tweet_print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```